# Android: sqlite_master always returning empty cursor

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to get a list of all of the tables in a database at runtime in my app, so I am using this command:

```
select * from sqlite_master;
```

However, no matter what, the resulting Cursor is empty. I know there are tables in the database because I can read and write from them, and this very same query returns what I expect when run it in the adb shell.

What could I be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess. Do you maybe use the same sqlite connection from two seperated threads? If you do, [that's the problem](http://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.

```
SELECT name FROM 
   (SELECT * FROM sqlite_master UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM sqlite_temp_master)
WHERE type='table'
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: Thanks, but that also returns an empty cursor.

Comment: Are you able to get data from other tables in the database?

Comment: Yes, I can insert and pull data from other tables just fine. This is for a light weight ORM I am creating, and I am working on having the library create/alter a table on the fly. Before running the "create table if not exists" query, I want to check if the table already exists or if it needs to be altered. Right now what happens is it queries the sqlite_master table for the table name in question, but currently it always comes back empty. Because of this, it fires off the "create table" command. Even after this, subsequent sqlite_master queries return an empty Cursor.

Comment: Any other ideas that might be causing this issue?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem that I was scratching my head about for a while, but it simply turned out that I hadn't opened the database.  Just a reminder for whomever else looks at this question.